# How to paste URL link of a copied hyperlink (NOT the text) in word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

I want to copy the underlying URL of a hyperlink not the display text of that link in Microsoft Word 2010.

Currently I can only have the option to paste `text only` - need a way to paste `link only`

[image]

How can I do that?

ps.

I need to copy multiple hyperlinks text (e.g. copied from the internet and paste into Word, then I need to extrack the link only). Currently when using the `Copy Link Address` option when copy, it works only for one link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just right-click the hyperlink and choose "Copy Link Address", "Copy Link Location" or similar option (depending on browser), and then you shouldn't need to choose any paste options at all.

Comment: Great tips. Thank you. Though, this cannot work for multiple hyperlink. The `Copy Link Address` is disabled. I have updated my OP to reflect this.

Comment: I see you added the multiple part to the question now.  If you copy multiple links into the clipboard, I think the best you're going to get in  Word 2010 is to right click them one by one within Word, choose "Copy Hyperlink" and then choose the "Keep Text Only" option under Paste (when you right click).  As soon as you have more than one hyperlink, as you noticed, all the options become greyed out.

Comment: Doing it manually is not what I need

Comment: I wish you luck then, because I don't think there is a way unless you write or find a custom macro.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely not the straight-forward answer you're hoping for, but it'd still be faster than manually copy-pasting one-by-one: go to view the page source and copy the block containing all the URL sources.  After pasting, you can use `find & replace` to quickly filter out what isn't needed, then manually clean the rest.